# Flask wtfforms on Post check with Jinja if file has been submmited

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2, wtforms

With jinja and flask-wtf
i am trying to see if the user summited a file or not

ON GET Request the `form.image1.data = None`
but on POST With no file summited i get

```
form.image1.data = <FileStorage: u'' ('application/octet-stream')>
```

The goal was to something like this but this doesn't work on POST

```
{% if form.image1.data ==  None %}
      No file uploaded
      {% endif %}
```